# Is there any way to use parallel to speed up a plotVenn() process?

Tags: r, performance, plot, parallel-processing, venn-diagram

I am trying to make a Venn diagram with 15 sets. I could do it with 9, using the `nVennR` package, but I had to plot it 22 times to compact the result.

```
myV <- createVennObj(nSets = 9, sNames = c( "NN","AdINI","AdTAR",
                                            "NN con NBI",
                                            "NN sin NBI",
                                            "AdINI con NBI",
                                            "AdINI sin NBI",
                                            "AdTAR con NBI",
                                            "AdTAR sin NBI"))

myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("NN con NBI", "NN"), 4343)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("NN sin NBI", "NN"), 22526)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("AdINI con NBI", "AdINI"), 2032)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("AdINI sin NBI", "AdINI"), 9545)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("AdTAR con NBI", "AdTAR"), 2641)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("AdTAR sin NBI", "AdTAR"), 10125)
i=0
while (i<22) {
        myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV, outFile='democentro.svg')
        i=i+1
}
```

It took several minutes but the result ended up being what I expected:
[image]
Now I want to do the same for 15 sets. Because the smaller sets, in the previous chart, are split in two. I've tried to do it but the process never ends, not even for the first plot.

Is there any way to use my computer's full potential for this?

[by the way, I'm using Windows 10 and I have 16 [GB] of RAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHzAp.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `nVennR` module is CPU-intensive, RAM is not an issue. The actual problem is that the number of points per line increases with the number of sets non-linearly. I fine-tuned that behavior so that up to nine sets could be rendered as fast as possible. I have been working on a new version of the algorithm that discards unnecessary points and can be much faster for a situation like yours. Unfortunately, I have not been able to port this version to `R` (I believe there is a scoping issue with `Rcpp`).

You can try that version from https://github.com/vqf/nVenn. You will find instructions on how to prepare your files there. You can even download the binary files for `Windows` at https://github.com/vqf/nVenn/tree/master/binaries/Win.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, my friend! And thanks for creating nVenn, it's fantastic. I have created the txt file which describes the regions of the Venn diagram. 15 sets are equal to 2^15 = 32,768 combinations +15 names + 1 Header = 32,784 lines. I got stuck after this step because I'm not familiarize with perl ... I downloaded ATOM and installed the `Run Script` package, but I couldn't run the script. I've been getting the following error: _"perl" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file_

Comment: That means you do not have perl installed. You can download it from http://strawberryperl.com/

Comment: Well, you were right and I apologize for my amateurism. Now I can run the script but I’m not getting any results. I'm sure the txt file is in the same folder as the .pl and has the structure you described
`=== Group analysis ===
=== nVenn input ===
nVenn v1.2
0

0

[Finished in 0.092s]`. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You can use `feed_venn_noheader.pl` to create the input file (something like `perl feed_venn_noheader.pl file1 file2 ... >venn.txt`. This should create the file `venn.txt` as input. If you run `nVenn.exe`, you get a prompt asking for the input file. If you run nVennOGL.exe, the input file has to be in the same folder, and its name has to be `venn.txt`. For this application, I would recommend `nVennOGL.exe`, as you can control the phases of the simulation by pressing `ESC`. Just press `ESC` when you are happy with the result, then again until it stops.

Comment: I think I'm getting close but I still can't.
I created all the txt files with the groups as you showed in ex1, ex2 and ex3. When I run `perl feed_venn_noheader.pl file1.txt ... file10.txt >venn.txt`, it returns the following error: `Bareword "venn" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at D:\ ...\feed_venn_noheader.pl line 83`
I read that maybe it can be solved by quoting, but I couldn't -or I haven't known how to- do it.

Comment: On the other hand, what I still don't understand is where it takes the values of each region. "file1 file2 ... file10" only describes how the regions are grouped, right? As I said in my last comment, I created a venn.txt file the way you mention it in .../binaries/Win ... is that useless?

Comment: If the `venn.txt` file follows the format (starts with a line containing `nVenn`, then the number of sets, ... as shown in the `Readme`), you should be able to run `nVennOGL.exe` directly. If it does not work, I think it would be best to open an issue on Github. This way, I can help you directly.

Comment: That's right, the file follows the format... and nothing happends when I run the `nVennOGL.exe`. I just opened an [issue on Github](https://github.com/vqf/nVenn/issues/3) as you suggested. Thank you